# need to get next Task in foreach

Tags: php, laravel, loops, laravel-5, foreach

My For each return the task same as in URL Now I need to get the next task

```
 @foreach ($Tasks as $Task)
    @if ($Task->slug == Request::segment(5))
      <h2>{{ $Task->task_name }}</h2>
    @endif

    @if ($loop->remaining)
      <p>Next Task is: {{ $Tasks[$loop->iteration]->task_name }}</p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

I get the task in URL so I need to get next task in foreach but it returns empty 
and tried

```
    @foreach ($ATask as $key => $Task)
      @if ($ATask[$key]->slug == Request::segment(5))
        <h2>{{ $Task->task_name }}</h2>
        <p>Next Task is: {{ $ATask[$key++]->task_name }}</p>

      @endif
   @endforeach
```

Comment: Instead of looping over all the tasks, aren't you better off simply doing 2 queries: 1 that matches the 5th Request segment, and another query that finds a Task with e.g. a higher ID or date than the first one? Then you don't need to do the foreach at all.

Comment: i need to get the one after Request::segment(5)   because ir reffrence to active task so i need to get next one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this script can slove your problem:

```
@foreach ($Tasks as $key => $Task)
    @if ($Task->slug == Request::segment(5))
      <h2>{{ $Task->task_name }}</h2>
      <p>Next Task is: {{ $Tasks[$key+1]->task_name }}</p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Hope it helps.

Also you can use `$key++` instead of `$key+1`

Comment: i'm getting this error Undefined offset: 1 (View: E:\Off Dev-College\DevCollege\resources\views\task.blade.php)

Comment: @KareemElsharkawy can you dump your `$Tasks` array please?

Comment: i tried $Key++ no error this time but i get same value

Comment: i get this error Undefined offset: 1 (View: E:\Off Dev-College\DevCollege\resources\views\task.blade.php)

Comment: @KareemElsharkawy there's user interface, no array. You can dump your array used `dd($ATasks);` function in controller

Comment: @KareemElsharkawy in a screen I have no see `<p>Next Task is..</p>` string. Do you `if statement` works like you need?

Comment: I have solved it it the problem was from ATask was having result of url not all tasks

Comment: @KareemElsharkawy I am pleased to you can slove this. Have a nice day :)